# Bootstrap navigation bar collapsing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have written a navigation bar based on the example given in the [components link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) in Bootstrap. But the navigation bar does not collapse in a right way as it is supposed to do.  As shown in the process below:

**State 1**
[image]

**State 2**
[image]

**State 3**
[image]

the navigation bar is not collapsed sharply, rather, it will become 2 columns first and then collapse.

I have found a same problem that has been asked previously in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113833/bootstrap-navigation-bar-doesnt-collapse-in-appropiate-way). It seems like the problem is caused by the default breaking point defined in bootstrap. However, I do not know where to change the breaking point and how can I do it.

I am using the latest bootstrap version, and following is the snippet of my navigation bar code.

Thanks in advance for any help and advice!

```
<!--navigation bar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header"><!--brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display-->

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navItems">

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a><!--end of logo-->

            </div><!--end of logo & collapsing logic-->

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navItems">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li><a href="#main" class="scroll">HOME</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#about" class="scroll">ABOUT</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#work" class="scroll">WORK</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#blog" class="scroll">BLOG</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll">CONTACT</a></li>

                </ul><!--end of menu list-->

                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search on this site" id="searchInput ">

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>

                </form><!--end of search bar-->

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li class="dropdown">

                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account <span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Settings</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Update Profile</a></li>

                            <li class="divider"></li>

                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Sign Out</a></li>

                        </ul><!--end of sub menu-->

                    </li><!--end of dropdown menu-->

                </ul><!end of the user account menu-->

            </div><!--end of collpased nav-->

        </div><!--end of container-->

    </nav><!--end of navbar-->
```

**Update**

I have looked into the solution provide by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827605/change-bootstrap-navbar-collapse-breakpoint-without-using-less), which does not work in the newest version of Bootstrap.

And I have locate the code block which defines the breakpoint of the collapsing effect:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

And I tried to modify the defined min-width, however I changed, it just does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827605/change-bootstrap-navbar-collapse-breakpoint-without-using-less

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try out first. If that solves the problem, I will update the solution.

Comment: It seems that "this doesn't work on Bootstrap 3 because there is another rule navbar-collapse.collapse which has display: block !important. Disabling that will result in the collapse button not appearing... ...a lot of classes that needs to be redefined, not just collapse" according to  @Daniele Ricci

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out:

To do this in the latest version:

I have modified three parts in the css file:

First you need to set when the navbar-header will float to left (in may case 1000px):

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

Then you will need to decide when all the menu button will be disappeared:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Last you need to define when the navbar-toggle will take effect:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Then just wait to see the magic happen:

When the screen reached the 1000px threshold:

From

[image]

To

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be able to override the default navbar collapse point like this.. (Assuming 1000 pixels in the new collapse point):

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/UQaiG0oNTR

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing [Bootstrap with SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass), in this way mixins are separeted and easier to manage.

With this configuiration the breaking-point is in your _variable mixins, and the _navbar  mixin just picks up the variable by default.

Overriding will work but it's probably neater if you keep coherency with bootstrap mixins.

Comment: This should probably be written as a comment instead of an answer, as this doesn't actually answer the original question. It's a valid point, but an incomplete answer.

Comment: the OP was talking about breakpoint;  even if you can find a precompiled Bootstrap CSS , breakpoint value is compiled in the _variable mixin so  for me it's important to know where that value comes from..

Comment: Look at the two answers on this post. They both solve the issue using CSS. Yours adds a suggestion, but doesn't provide a complete answer, hence why I recommend added it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation that you yourself linked to!

> ### [Overflowing content](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)
>
> Since Bootstrap doesn't know how much space the content in your navbar needs, **you might run into issues with content wrapping into a second row**. To resolve this, you can:
>
> - Reduce the amount or width of navbar items.
> - Hide certain navbar items at certain screen sizes using responsive utility classes.
> - Change the point at which your navbar switches between collapsed and horizontal mode. Customize the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable or add your own media query.